# How to merge two tab-separated files and predefine formatting of missing values?

Tags: bash

I am trying to merge two unsorted tab separated files by a column of partially overlapping identifiers (gene#) with the option of predefining missing values and keeping the order of the first table.

When using `paste` on my two example tables missing values end up as empty space.

```
cat file1
c3  100 300 gene4
c1  300 400 gene1
c13 600 700 gene2

cat file2
gene1   4.2 0.001
gene4   1.05    0.5

paste file1 file2
c3  100 300 gene1   gene1   4.2 0.001
c1  300 400 gene4   gene4   1.05    0.5
c13 600 700 gene2
```

As you see the result not surprisingly shows empty spaces in non matched lines. Is there a way to keep the order of file1 and fill lines like the third as follows:

```
c3  100 300 gene4   gene4   1.05 0.5
c1  300 400 gene1   gene1   4.2    0.001
c13 600 700 gene2   NA   1    1
```

I assume one way could be to build an `awk` conditional construct. It would be great if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is `gene1` supposed to connect to `gene1` or you are just trying to append `NA 1 1` to `file2` until it has the same number of lines as `file1` ? To use `join` the files has to be sorted.

Comment: Yes, the gene column should be used to connect. Ideally line-by-line of `file1` should be checked for a matching gene entry in any line in `file2`. If something is found the two extra columns of file2 should be appended, if nothing is found `NA 1 1` should be appended. Thanks.

Comment: Can we sort it? Does the initial order matter? Are the `gene1` unique (there are no two `gene1` lines?)? You can use `sort` with `join` with `-e "NA 1 1"`

Comment: We can sort it if that helps, granted we could sort it afterwards to the original order using `file1` (first column: `c3, c1, c13`) as some sort of sorting key? The genes are definitely unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` please try the following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$1; b[$1]=$2; c[$1]=$3; next}
    {if (!a[$4]) {a[$4]="N/A"; b[$4]=1; c[$4]=1}
     printf "%s  %s  %s  %s\n", $0, a[$4], b[$4], c[$4]}
' file2 file1
```

which yields:

```
c3  100 300 gene1  gene1  4.2  0.001
c1  300 400 gene4  gene4  1.05  0.5
c13 600 700 gene2  N/A  1  1
```

awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$1; b[$1]=$2; c[$1]=$3; next}
    {if (!a[$4]) {a[$4]="N/A"; b[$4]=1; c[$4]=1}
     printf "%s  %s  %s  %s\n", $0, a[$4], b[$4], c[$4]}
' file2 file1

**[Explanations]**

- In the 1st line, `FNR==NR { command; next}` is an idiom to execute the command only when reading the 1st file in the argument list ("file2" in this case). Then it creates maps (aka associative arrays) to associate values in "file2" to `genes`

as:

```
gene1 => gene1 (with array a)
gene1 => 4.2   (with array b)
gene1 => 0.001 (with array c)
gene4 => gene4 (with array a)
gene4 => 1.05  (with array b)
gene4 => 0.5   (with array c)
```

- It is not necessary that "file2" is sorted.
- The following lines are executed only when reading the 2nd file ("file1") because these lines are skipped when reading the 1st file due to the `next` statement.
- The line `{if (!a[$4]) ..` is a fallback to assign variables to default values when the associative array `a[gene]` is undefined (meaning the `gene` is not found in "file2").
- The final line prints the contents of "file1" followed by the associated values via the `gene`.

Comment: Seems to work great. Could you point me towards a source I can read on understanding your code? I am trying to apply this solution to various different tasks and therefore need to understand how to adapt to different files.

Comment: Sure, I'll update my answer with some explanations in a couple of hours.

Comment: I've added explanations in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`:

```
join -e NA -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 2.1 2.2 2.3' -a 1 -1 5 -2 1 <(nl -w1 -s ' ' file1 | sort -k 5) <(sort -k 1 file2) | sed 's/NA\sNA$/1 1/' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

`-e NA` — replace all missing values with `NA`

`-o ...` —  output format (field is specified using `<file>.<field>`)

`-a 1` — Keep every line from the left file

`-1 5`, `-2 1` — Fields used to join the files

`file1`, `file2` — The files

`nl -w1 -s ' ' file1` — file1 with numbered lines

`<(sort -k X fileN)` — File N ready to be joined on column X

`s/NA\sNA$/1 1/` — Replace every `NA NA` on end of line with `1 1`

`| sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-` — sort numerically and remove the first column

---

The example above uses spaces on output. To use tabs, append `| tr ' ' '\t'`:

```
join -e NA -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.1 2.2 2.3' -a 1 -1 4 -2 1 file1 file2 | sed 's/NA\sNA$/1 1/' | tr ' ' '\t'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your explanations. On my example code it works, however when I tried it with my analysis case I get the following error message: `join: file 1 is not in sorted order`
`join: file 2 is not in sorted order` Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I adjusted the example above by changing the order of the gene column now generating a similar error `join: file 1 is not in sorted order`

Comment: @gdeniz I think it is fixed

Comment: Does this work without having to sort the `file1`, because in my real world case `file1` is the result of a clustering program that generated a specific data-dependent order?

Comment: @gdeniz The last sort restores the order.

Answer (score 0):

The broken lines have a TAB as the last character. Fix this with

```
paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\t$/\tNA\t1\t1/g'
```